# Python- Filling Spaces in a List Between Two Elements with Recursion

Tags: python, string, list, recursion

I have a potential list that will be given to me as in a form like this:

```
['A', '-', 'A', 'a', '-', '-','-','a','A','-','-']
```

Using recursion, I need to fill the spaces between alike elements, or to the ends of the list list like this:

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'a', 'a', 'a','a','a','A','A','A']
```

I was able to do this without recursion, however I am confused by how one can perform this recursively. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think the desired output will contain space in-between. `['A', 'A', 'A', 'a', 'a', 'a','a','a','A','A','A']` will be converted to `['A','A','A','a','a','a','a','a','A','A','A']` automatically by python. 
I guess you want to add space within element of list, is it ?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is, check if `'-'` is present in the `list`, if yes replace a single `'-'` with neighboring element and recurse again, if no, return `list`.

```
lst = ['A', '-', 'A', 'a', '-', '-','-','a','A','-','-']
def recur(lst):
    if '-' in lst:    
        for i, j in enumerate(lst):
            if j == '-':
                try:
                    lst[i] = lst[i-1]
                except IndexError:
                    lst[i] = lst[i+1]
                return recur(lst)
    else: return lst
print(recur(lst))
```

OR, without loop:

```
def recur(lst):
    if '-' in lst:    
        i = lst.index('-')
        try:
            lst[i] = lst[i-1]
        except IndexError:
            lst[i] = lst[i+1]
        return recur(lst)
    else: return lst
```

**EDIT**:
Above method will exceed maximum recursion depth, if the sequence starts with two `-`s. In that case, you can do:

```
def recur(lst):
    if '-' in lst:    
        for i, j in enumerate(lst):
            if j == '-':
                try:
                    lst[i] = lst[i-1]
                except IndexError:
                    lst[i] = lst[i+1]
                if lst[i] != '-': return recur(lst)

    else: return lst
```

Output:

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to implement this without the use of except IndexError?

Comment: Yes, replace `try:` with `if i!= 0:` and replace `except IndexError:` to `else:`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion with list slicing:

```
data = ['A', '-', 'A', 'a', '-', '-','-','a','A','-','-']
def update_dash(d, start='A'):
   return [] if not d else [d[0] if d[0] != '-' else start]+update_dash(d[1:], d[0] if d[0].isalpha() else start)

print(update_dash(data))
```

Output:

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def rec(_list, currentIndex, prevChar):
    if currentIndex == len(_list): # End of list
        return
    if _list[currentIndex]=='-': # If current character is '-', replace it with previous character
        _list[currentIndex] = prevChar
    rec(_list,currentIndex+1,_list[currentIndex]) # Recurse for rest of the list

_list1  = ['A', '-', 'A', 'a', '-', '-','-','a','A','-','-']
_list2  = ['-', 'A', '-',]
# Assuming initial `prevChar` is 'A' for cases when list starts directly with '-' characters. Ex ['-','A','-']
rec(_list1,0,'A')
rec(_list2,0,'A')
print(_list1)
print(_list2)
```